# "set" version of field_get_items?

Tags: entities

One can retrieve field items from an entity with

```
// Find all terms on $node in field 'field_tags'.
$terms = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags');
```

But is there a convenient way to do the reverse, Core, or otherwise?

```
// Attach new term $term to $node in field 'field_tags'.
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$node = field_set_items('node', $node, 'field_tags', 'taxonomy_term', $term);
node_save($node);
```

I would like to avoid the hassle of manually assigning a $term, go look in devel what the array structure looks like and then build the array by hand, as it is sometimes non-trivial.

The only issue in the core queue I could find that looked vaguely similar was about the [field language api DX](http://drupal.org/node/1260640).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such function.

See my comment at [Language support for entity fields](http://drupal.org/node/1500308#comment-5794848).

Comment: Thanks Berdir. I was hoping you'd show up ;) and I was also afraid you'd say so. The problem with the code in your comment is that for a lot of fields, 'value' may be insufficient or just plain wrong.

Comment: field_get_items() does not help you with that either, it returns an array of items that contain value. Or whatever the field type defines. There is no way to abstract that.

Comment: For example, field_get_items() returns array(array('tid' => 123)). Your code needs to know that field_tags is a taxonomy term reference and that it has the tid key set *and* that it is a teference to a taxonomy term.

Comment: The comments are no longer visible at that page  as per given link.

Comment: Comments are on the discuss page now: https://www.drupal.org/node/1500308/discuss

Answer (score 2):

For such a function to exist, `field_set_items()` would need to be able to identify the `stdClass` object as that of a taxonomy term, and also map it to a function that can decode the object and create a field array out of it.

Since there's no core function to do that, I don't think this will be easy.

Comment: It's terribly irritating that there's no $entity->entity_type property [(yet)](http://drupal.org/node/1042822), but regardless, that could easily be added to my example callback. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: The lack of an `entity_type` isn't really the problem IMHO...the problem is exactly what you've added to your question: "it is sometimes non-trivial". Because the data is non-trivial, for `field_set_items` to work as you desire, each field type in the system would need to implement some sort of interface describing how to reverse-engineer the data array from an object/arbitrary variable.

Answer (score 2):

Although this doesn't help building the some times complicated array structure, I see that what I'm looking for has to some extent been introduced in Drupal 8. Perhaps it will be extended further in the future. :)

[New simpler API available for accessing fields, properties and language information](http://drupal.org/node/1532946).

Example usage from the linked page:

```
<?php
// Change a field value.
$body = $comment->get('comment_body');
$body[0]['value'] = 'This is actually a perverted tango';
$comment->set('comment_body', $body);
```