# Is there a better way of getting specific pieces of data from taxonomy_term_load()?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy that has several fields attached to it. If I do a `taxonomy_term_load($tid)` on a specific item, it returns a huge object with multiple levels of nested arrays. I know which "parent" item (i.e. field name) I want, so I can do something like this:

```
$track_tax = taxonomy_term_load($value);
var_dump($track_tax->field_track_icon);
```

But even this returns a lot of nested levels:

```
array(1) {
  ["und"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(15) {
      ["fid"]=>
      string(3) "702"
      ["alt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["width"]=>
      string(2) "36"
      ["height"]=>
      string(2) "36"
      ["uid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["filename"]=>
      string(24) "strategies_at_retail.jpg"
      ["uri"]=>
      string(44) "public://track_icon/strategies_at_retail.jpg"
      ["filemime"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["filesize"]=>
      string(4) "1129"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(10) "1338391429"
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "image"
      ["rdf_mapping"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["image_dimensions"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["width"]=>
        string(2) "36"
        ["height"]=>
        string(2) "36"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can get the uri by doing something like this:

```
$uri = $track_tax->field_track_icon["und"][0]["uri");
```

Is there a better way? Some other function that will return specific pieces? Or do I need to address it level by level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function is very useful for this sort of thing. It doesn't produce shorter code, but it's more structured and a lot easier to get your head round than the endless arrays of data:

```
// Get the items for a particular field
$field_items = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $track_tax, 'field_track_icon');

// Get the first item (fields can have multiple items so field_get_items always returns an array)
$first_item = array_shift($field_items);

// Get the URI
$uri = $first_item['uri'];
```

Using that method has the added benefit of automatic language negotiation, so you can avoid having to get that from context or just relying on `'und'`.

I should also say the use of this function isn't limited to taxonomy terms; you can use it to get field values for any type of entity.

Comment: Thanks. So, for the param you have as `$term`, is that the tid or the term value?

Comment: Sorry should have noticed that, it's the term object which is `$track_tax` in your code

Comment: OK, so I still need to do the taxonomy_term_load, but then I can use field_get_items on the particular field attached to the taxonomy? Sounds good.

Comment: Yep spot on. There's also the `entity_metadata_wrapper()` function if you're using the Entity API module which does something similar, have a look at [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33444/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-entity-metadata-wrapper-function-and-why-should-i) for more info