# How to save custom fields when using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter?

Tags: 7, forms

I am implementing `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. I have managed to setup for, and be able to collect custom values from the fields. When I submit the form, the node is created without my custom fields (i.e field_1 an field_2).

```
function mymodule_form_AYG_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $options_first = _mymodule_get_first_dropdown_options();

  $selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_1']) ? $form_state['values']['field_1'] : key($options_first);

  $form['field_1'] = array(
    '#weight'=> -15,
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'field 1',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#default_value' => $selected,    
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      // 'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
    ),
  );

   $form['field_2'] = array(
    '#weight'=> -14,
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'field:',

    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

    '#options' => _mymodule_get_second_dropdown_options($selected),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['field_2']) ? $form_state['values']['field_2'] : '',
  );


  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, $form_state) {    
  // I can see values for the custom fields here. 
  // How do I store them in the node?
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

I have installed the Entity API module, and tried the proposed solution. It gives me an error.

```
function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node']; 
  $node = node_load(arg(1));

  krumo($node);  // Getting FALSE here

  $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $obj->field_1 = $form_state['values']['field_1'];
  $obj->field_2 = $form_state['values']['field_2'];
  $obj->save(); 
}
```

This is the error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 735 of E:\wamp\www\Classified\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: Why not just use a standard Field API field?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing your form alter has done it added fields to a form. But you need somewhere to store the values of those fields.

When you add a field to an entity (node) using the Field UI module Drupal creates 2 database tables. One to store the field values and one to store older revisions of that fields value. Without these tables you don't have anywhere to store the values.

Here are steps to add that field your node bundle:

1. Make sure the Field UI module is enabled.
2. From the admin toolbar visit Structure > Content types > AYG (the name of your node type) > Manage fields.
3. On this page add your new fields and configure as required.

Now your new fields will show on your node creation / edit forms and you will have tables to store the values of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of saving field values to a node is by using the [entity_metadata_wrapper()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) function that comes with the [Entity module](http://drupal.org/project/entity). It makes it easier for you to set or get values to and from a node object, or any other entity.

[There is a good explanation of entity_metadata_wrapper() here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33444/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-entity-metadata-wrapper-function-and-why-should-i).

So in your case, with the Entity module installed, you'd do something like:

```
// get the node object 
$nid = $form['nid']['#value'];
$node = node_load($nid);

// create the helper object 
$obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

// add the field data
$obj->field_1 = $form_state['values']['field_1'];
$obj->field_2 = $form_state['values']['field_2'];

// save the data
$obj->save();
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply Web. i have tried but came up with error. i dont know how to put code in reply but i have edited the actual question with code and error please have a look. I am a biginner so please ignore anything stupid :). thanks

Comment: Are you sure the data you are saving is in the correct format of the field type? What type of field are you using and what type of data are you trying to save? For example, if you are using an integer field type, you cannot save a string value, etc.

Comment: krumo($form); [nid]['#value'] is null. its just a general form anf fields are getting vocabulary terms as their values from the database.

Comment: You just need to put the node id into node_load(). Perhaps you can take this from arg(1), assuming the URL is node/%node/edit

Comment: Actually, I think you have access to the nid via $form_state['values']['nid']

Comment: thats also NULL. i am trying to get nid from somewhere let you know if it worked. this is my local url http://localhost/mysite/?q=node/add/ayg

Comment: well well how can we have nid if its not saved yet. my form is taking these values from the user and saving it as a node. i am using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter.

Comment: I see, apologies, I assumed you were altering the node edit form. You can still do the same thing, you just need to change your submit handler so your custom submit function happens after node creation. Use $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit'; instead.

Comment: thanks again but no luck. same "Invalid data value given" again i have made sure that data type is String.

Comment: nid is there but $node = node_load($nid); is NULL now

Comment: Okay, not sure why that is, but forget node_load. I think the node object is available in $form['#node'], so you could do $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $form['#node']); instead?

Comment: or $form_state['node'].

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here...from the code in the OP it doesn't look like these are field API fields, but rather custom fields that are being added to the form. @Waqas That's not how entities work in Drupal - if you want data to be stored against the node, you need to add a field using the Field UI (or API if you're comfortable with that), or add a custom table and save the data to it in `hook_node_insert()/hook_node_update()` and load it back on to the node object with `hook_node_load()`

Comment: You are probably right, I was assuming the OP was talking about fields, as stated in the question.

Comment: yes you are right Clive. I have created a content type and created most of the elements by using Field UI. But i have to insert these three or four fields using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter because their options are dependent on each other (Cascading select). So now when everthing is in place when i click save only elements created by UI get saved. what i understand from your answer Clive, i have to make those extra select fields in UI and then access them using hook_form_alter in custom module. will then they save automatically when i click save? thanks

Comment: i would really appreciate any more ideas guys? thanks

Comment: See [Dynamic select list in the form (dependent dropdown)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown)

Comment: Where this should be called ? will it create field tables and store in it appropriately ?

Answer (score 0):

For saving custom form element values, you have to implement hook_node_insert() in your module. I hope [this tutorial](http://phpgainers.com/content/how-save-and-update-custom-field-value-node-form-drupal-7) will help you to understand.